# How do I get a certificate to sign a file and make it trusted?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, https, encryption, lets-encrypt

I may not be using the correct words to describe what I'm trying to do, but I'd like to have my own certificate to digitally sign files so they can be "trusted". I'm very technical, but have little experience using certs.

I have a domain and it's hosted on `Wix`, which uses automatic managed `SSL` certs. First, do I need a public/private SSL certificate in order to digitally sign files?

`SSL` certificates, from what I read, seem to be used mainly for adding `https` to your website. Am I getting different types of certificates mixed up? Or does one also use an `SSL` cert to sign files?

If I sign a file (somehow) I'd imagine with my private key, would I distribute the public key with the file, and the end-user would just add it to their trusted CA's?

Comment: There's a great summary at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89319/creating-my-own-ca-for-an-intranet of how to run your own CA.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks for the summary, but how would I incorporate or prove I own my domain when it's hosted on `Wix`? Wouldn't I need to connect whatever commands I'm running to some sort of `C Record` or something?

Comment: I think you're mixing up SSL and signing files. If you want to sign files, use something like PGP. https://keybase.io/ is a good tool for that.

Comment: It's possible I'm mixing up, but I need whatever it is to be associated with my `.com` domain and verifiable, that's why I'm thinking it's an SSL cert.

Comment: Wix will not give you the SSL certificate they hold. You can get a SSL certificate via a separate vendor (who will make you prove you own the domain), but it's probably going to be easier to just host the file *on* the domain, which pretty clearly proves its provenance. It isn't very typical to sign files with an SSL certificate, though.

Comment: Ah I think I follow now. So I'd just use `OpenSSL` to generate whatever key I wanted, then throw it on the server and that'd prove to end users I own it...but it wouldn't show as "trusted" unless I actually got the `Wix` key?

Comment: Well, let's back up a minute. How are your end-users verifying these files? How do you intend for them to check the signing?

Comment: I was thinking something along the way this works: https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Sign_and_verify_text_files_to_public_keys_via_the_OpenSSL_Command_Line.html or am I way lost?

Comment: You are, sorta. What you'd typically do is sign files via a PGP key. You'd then put your public portion of your key up on your website. Users interested in validating the signature can get the public key from your website (which proves it's associated with the domain) and verify the signature with that.

Comment: So that method of using an SSL cert to sign a file is basically so I could do the same thing as a PGP key, except the file would be verified against the public SSH cert associated with the domain, where if I used a PGP key, I'd post some public key-string next to my file download and they'd verify the download with that string?

Comment: Yes. The latter is commonly used. Using an SSL certificate to do the signing is not, and I've never run into a file verification client that'd go "oh yeah, this is associated with example.com" that I can recall.

Comment: Gotcha. That clears things up a bit. Not sure how to accept your comments as an answer.

Comment: Are you asking about digitally signing Windows executables?